# python3 JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I'm facing this error in python3.6.

My json file looks like this:

```
{
"id":"776", 
"text":"Scientists have just discovered a bizarre pattern in global weather. Extreme heat waves like the one that hit the Eastern US in 2012, leaving at least 82 dead, don't just come out of nowhere."
}
```

It's encoding 'utf-8' and I checked it online, it is a valid json file. I tried to load it in this way:

```
p = 'doc1.json'
json.loads(p)
```

I tried this as well:

```
p = "doc1.json"
with open(p, "r") as f:
    doc = json.load(f)
```

The error is the same:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Anyone can help? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extra Data: Line 1 column 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48332385/extra-data-line-1-column-2)

Answer (score 3):

```
p = 'doc1.json'
json.loads(p)
```

you're asking the json module to load the string 'doc1.json' which obviously isn't valid json, it's a filename.

You want to open the file, read the contents, then load the contents using json.loads():

```
p = 'doc1.json'
with open(p, 'r') as f:
    doc = json.loads(f.read())
```

As suggested in the comments, this could be further simplified to:

```
p = 'doc1.json'
with open(p, 'r') as f:
    doc = json.load(f)
```

where `jon.load()` takes a file handle and reads it for you.

Comment: You can use `json.load(f)` to simplify things slightly. And JSON is a text format, not a binary one so you should open with just 'r' (which is the default anyway).

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, and time.

Comment: Funny thing. Getting the same error with proper loading the file in .load

Answer (score 0):

## Aside

First, your path is not really a path. My response won't be about that, but your path should be something like `'.path/to/the/doc1.json'` (this example is a relative path).

## TL;DR

`json.loads` is for loading `str` objects directly; `json.load` wants a `fp` or *file pointer* object which represents a file.

## Solution

It appears you are misusing `json.loads` vs `json.load` (notice the `s` in one and not the other). I believe the `s` stands for string or Python object type `str` though I may be wrong. There is a very important distinction here; your path is represented by a string, but you actually care about the file as an object.

So of course this breaks because `json.loads` thinks it is trying to parse a type `str` object that is actually an invalid json:

```py
path = 'a/path/like/this/is/a/string.json'
json.loads(path)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
...
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Using this properly would look something like this:

```py
json_str = '{"hello": "world!"}'
json.loads(json_str)

# The expected output.
{'hello': 'world!'}
```

Since `json.loads` does not meet our needs—it can, however it is extra and unnecessary code—we can use its friend `json.load`. `json.load` wants its first parameter to be an `fp`, but what is that? Well, it stands for *file pointer* which is a fancy way of saying "an object that represents a file." This has to do with opening a file to do something to or with it. In our case, we want to read the file into `json.load`.

We will use the context manager `open()` since that is a good thing to do. Note, I do not know what the contents of your `doc1.json` is so I replaced the output with my own.

```py
path = 'path/to/the/doc1.json'
with open(path, 'r') as fp:
    print(json.load(fp))

# The expected output.
{'hello': 'world!'}
```

Generally, I think I would use `json.load` a lot more than `json.loads` (with the s) since I read directly from json files. If you load some json into your code using a third party package, you may find your self reading that in your code and then passing as a `str` to `json.loads`.

## Resources

1. Python's json — https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json